# showing equality of two exponential integrals

Tags: integration, exponential-function

We want to show the following:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(-y-y^2)/(2c^2)}dy =\int_{0}^{\infty} c \cdot e^{-y^2 - 2cy}dy$

To the best of my abilities, I have tried the standard tricks including u-substitution, integration by parts, etc., but I wind up either having to perform another substitution or another integration by parts.

Intuition that I am unable to translate/verify tells me that in order to bring the $c$ down, I should somehow derive $2c^2$ with respect to $c$.

Can someone please provide some suggestions?

Comment: These integrals are not equal. substitute $c=1$ then $0.876\not=0.379$.

Comment: I guess they are equal when $c\approx 0.411676$.

Comment: and $c\approx. -0.7055$.

Comment: @Inquisor well at least I know i'm not going crazy now. I copied this from an example in my textbook whose details were left to the reader, maybe there was a typo in the book. thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Completing the squares and assuming $c>0$, you face the gaussian integral making
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{y+y^2}{2 c^2}}\,dy=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} c\, e^{\frac{1}{8 c^2}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}
   c}\right)$$
$$\int_0^\infty c\, e^{-(2 c y+y^2)}\,dy=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi }\, c\, e^{c^2} \text{erfc}(c)$$

As said in comments, they are equal only if $c=0.4117$